# How to specify a point belong to an ellipse?

Tags: pstricks

```
\documentclass[border=15pt,pstricks,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl,pst-calculate}

\begin{document}
\degrees[36]
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-3,-3)(4,4)
\def\a{2}
\def\xa{\pscalculate{\a*cos(5)}}
\def\ya{\pscalculate{(\a/4)*sin(5)}}
\psellipse(0,0)(+\a,\a/4)
\pstGeonode[PosAngle=-45](\xa,\ya){A}
\pscircle{2}
\multido{\i=0+1}{36}{\psdot(2;\i)}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Question: How to specify a point belong to an ellipse? P\s: The syntax (r;angle) help to specify a point belong to a circle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
x = a cos t
y = b sin t
```

is the parameterization of an ellipse but the `t` does not correspond to the angle of position vector `(x,y)`. Let `Θ` be the angle of position vector.
It is easy to show that `tan t = (a sin Θ) / (b cos Θ)`.

The remaining will be self-explanatory. :-)

```
\documentclass[border=15pt,pstricks,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl,pst-calculate}

\begin{document}
\foreach \THETA in {60,150,240,330}{%
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-4,-4)(4,4)
\psline[linecolor=red](3;\THETA)
\psellipse(0,0)(3,2)
\qdisk(!3 2 2 copy exch \THETA\space sin mul exch \THETA\space cos mul atan PtoCab){2pt}
\end{pspicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

## Explanation

- `3 2 2 copy`  produces  `3 2 3 2`
- `exch` produces `3 2 2 3`
- `\THETA\space sin mul`  produces `3 2 2 3*sin(Θ)`
- `exch` produces `3 2 3*sin(Θ) 2`
- `\THETA\space cos mul` produces `3 2 3*sin(Θ) 2*cos(Θ)`
- `atan` produces `3 2 t`
- `PtoCab` produces `x y`
- `PtoCab` needs 3 operands `a b t` that will be converted to `a*cos(t) b*sin(t)`.
- `atan` needs 2 operands `y x` to produces a quadrant-dependent angle.

## Final Release

```
\documentclass[border=15pt,pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\pstVerb{/P2EC {3 copy sin 3 -1 roll mul 3 -1 roll cos 3 -1 roll mul atan PtoCab} bind def}
\begin{document}
\foreach \THETA in {60,150,240,330}{%
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-4,-4)(4,4)
\psline[linecolor=red](3;\THETA)
\psellipse(0,0)(3,2)
\qdisk(!3 2 \THETA\space P2EC){2pt}
\end{pspicture}}
\end{document}
```

I introduce a new macro `P2EC` (Polar to Elliptical Cartesian) that will convert `a b Θ` to `a*b*cos Θ/sqrt(a^2 * sin^2 Θ + b^2 * cos^2 Θ) a*b*sin Θ/sqrt(a^2 * sin^2 Θ + b^2 * cos^2 Θ)`.

Comment: Hi, with your final code, what is the _roll_ and _bind_? :-)

Comment: @chishimotoji: 




`a b c d e 3 1 roll` produces `a b e c d`.

`a b c d e 3 -1 roll` produces `a b d e c`.

`a b c d e 3 2 roll` produces `a b d e c`.